# Close or delete meta tag from html file

Tags: c#, html, xml, pdf, xslt

I want to convert a xml file to pdf. I have a xsl transformation to make a html file and then convert that into the final pdf file but when the xsl tranformation make the html file add a meta tag without close it.

I want to know how can I close that tag in c# code or delete it because when I apply the pdf convertion the exception is: "Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link."

Comment: you should look into fixing the xsl transform that's producing the bad html, instead of trying to clean up the mess it leaves.

Comment: `META` is an element without a closing tag (it's an unclosed element like `IMG`). Fix the transformation.

Comment: This is my declaration in the xsl file <xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:cfdi='http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3'>
 <xsl:output method = "html" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your output instruction to::

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

This will prevent the XSLT processor from automatically adding the `meta` element to your `head` element (if you want it, you will have to add it explicitly).